# Select next line after match is found using split

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

thanks for reading.

im working in a small powershell script.. the idea is to parse this information

```
      Hostname:
    xxxxx-CS0,xxxx
    Network:
    IPv4 Address            = xxxxx
    IPv4 Netmask            = 255.255.254.0
    IPv4 Gateway            = xxxxx
    DNS Servers             = xxxxx
Hostname:
xxxxx,8.1.9-184
Network:
IPv4 Address            = xxxxx
IPv4 Netmask            = xxxxx
IPv4 Gateway            = xxxxxx
DNS Servers             = xxxxxx
Hostname:
xxxxxx,7.1.80-7
Network:
IPv4 Address            = xxxx
IPv4 Netmask            = xxxxx
IPv4 Gateway            = xxxxx
DNS Servers             = xxxxx
```

So.. i allready got all the information unless the hostname with this code

```
  $info = Get-Content C:\xxxxxx\IP_info_all.txt

 write-host "Network Information VNX"



   ForEach ($network in $info)  {


   $hostname = ($network -split "`n")
   if($hostname -match "Hostname")
   {
   Write-Host $hostname
   $hostname =""
   }


     $b = ($network -split " ")[1]
     if ($b -match "Address") {
        $b
        $c = ($network -split "=")[1]
        $c
      if  ($name -match "IPv4"){
    $name
    $copyname =($network -split ":")[0]
     }
      }


     $b = ($network -split " ")[1]
     if ($b -match "Netmask") {
        $b 
         $maskid = ($network -split "=")[1]
         $maskid }

    $d = ($network -split " ")[1]
    if ($d -match "Gateway") {
            $d
     $Gatewayid = ($network -split "=")[1]
     $Gatewayid
     }


     $z = ($network -split " ")[1]
     $v = "DNS"
     if ($z -match "Servers") 
     {
     $v 
     $dnsserverid = ($network -split "=")[1,2,3]
     $dnsserverid
     }
```

And the output giveme the names and the numbers of the network information, but i don't know how can i get the next line under "Hostname" string.

and i need the output this way:

```
Network Information VNX
Hostname:
Address
 xxxx
Netmask
 xxxx
Gateway
 xxxx
DNS
 xxxx
Hostname:

Address
 xxxx
Netmask
 xxxx
```

Thanks!

Comment: edited it a few times but it should give you what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through each line. When setting up your conditional statements add 1 to symbolize I want to read the next line like this...

```
$info = Get-Content "C:\xxxxxx\IP_info_all.txt"
    write-host "Network Information VNX"
$content = ($info -split "`n") 

For($i=0;$i -lt $content.count;$i++){

    if($content[$i] -match "Hostname:")
    {
        "Hostname"
        Write-Host $content[$i+1]
    }
    elseif($content[$i] -match "Network:")
    {
        "Network"
        Write-Host ($content[$i]  -split "=")[1]
    }
    elseif($content[$i] -match "IPv4 Address")
    {
        "Address"
        Write-Host ($content[$i]  -split "=")[1]
    }
    elseif($content[$i] -match "IPv4 Netmask")
    {
        "Netmask"
        Write-Host ($content[$i] -split "=")[1]
    }
    elseif($content[$i] -match "IPv4 Gateway")
    {
        "Gateway"
        Write-Host ($content[$i] -split "=")[1]
    }
    elseif($content[$i] -match "DNS Servers")
    {
        "DNS Servers"
        Write-Host ($content[$i] -split "=")[1]
    }
}
```

Comment: the output is the same :S

Comment: i need to get the hostname output, like this: xxxxx-CS0,xxxx . so if i use split with 0 or 1, im still in the same line, i need to get the line under "hostname" string, i don't know if this is more clear. Thanks for help

Comment: yes your code now works nice, but it only works with the first content, i need to parse a 3000 code line, that's why i was using "if" in order to check all the contents, edited in the main question is the example of the output that i need, only need to get the hostname :S